# What is an appropriate HTTP status code for a flow where a client is asked for more information before proceeding?

Tags: angular, reactjs, single-page-application, http-status-codes

We have a single page application which has a series of forms required to process a complete "new application".

Steps like "enter email", "verify email", "verify mobile number", etc

The flow of the steps is based on the previous step and can vary based on the user's journey (where they came from, what they've provided, etc).

This process is orchestrated by the server by the client hitting a `/continue` endpoint.

The user journey can vary e.g.

```
Step 1 -> Step 2 -> Step 4 -> Step 5 -> Complete
Step 1 -> Step 2 -> Step 3 -> Complete
Step 1 -> Step 2 -> Step 3 -> Step 4 -> Step 5 -> Complete
```

On each step, the `/continue` endpoint will return the next required step of the process until there are no steps left, at which point it will resolve a `204`.

When the user is required to complete an action before continuing, we tell the SPA what page to display by issuing a `requiredAction` in the response

```
{
    "requiredAction": "STEP_3"
}
```

The question is, what is the appropriate status code for requesting more stuff from the client?

I see that `303` might be as in the [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/303) it states that it:

> indicates that the redirects don't link to the newly uploaded resources but to another page, like a confirmation page or an upload progress page.

Answer (score 0):

303 is a reasonable response if you want the client to *Navigate* to the URL you provide in the `Location` header.

If you want to return data that the client will inspect, after which the client will determine on its own that it needs to do something more, like hit the `/continue` URL with some kind of complex request, then that data you returned is a complete response to a successful request and you should return it with a 200 status code.